# Generate component diagram from source code in EA

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I'm currently working on EA. I have a task to generate UML diagram from source code by using EA. I found the way to generate class diagram. But i need to generate component diagram directly from source code.

I have analyzed and found that it is possible using one of the three methods :

1.Scripting,

2.Grammar Editors,

3.Code Generation.

Could anyone help me to know the procedure to generate component diagram automatically....

Comment: 1. is the only option since 2 and 3 won't help you here. Anyhow, a detailed answer would take too much space here.

Comment: In your world, what level of granularity do you consider to be a component? Code library? Code location on disk? Conceptual subsystem? Some are only in the mind and may not be automatable.

Comment: @Thomas Kilian If it is possible using scripting could you please explain how to link my c source code file with my script...

Comment: Honestly no. I'd voted to close this question as too broad.

Comment: You are basically asking something like "how do I write a compiler?", which is way to broad for this site.

Comment: Does anyone know how to use scripting for reverse engineering

Comment: To be honest I'd just write a .NET plugin for it. Reverse engineer the code to classes, then run you plugin (or script) over the classes that you've sucked in to emit components as you see fit. I'm not sure what you'd be looking for in the classes mind to tell you what a component is -- that would be up to you. Start here for add-ins. https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12/automation_and_scripting/creatingaddins.html